# asp.net C# slow loading time when using sqldatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, objectdatasource

I need to present a report that has three filters something like

```
select * from foo where condition 1 and condition 2 and condition 3
```

So I'm using an object datasource and bound the three parameters to three different drop downs and it works great, however I've been asked that the first option in the drop down would be "All" - meaning no filter.
Since i know how to do it only with sqldata source I switched the control and used the following code

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Tickets_data]  ORDER BY [Open_Time]"
            FilterExpression="[Lote] like '{0}%'">
           <FilterParameters>
          <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropLote" Name="Lote" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String"/>
            </FilterParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

It's working, but loading time is very slow like 9 or 10 seconds, and each refresh in the dropdown is also extremly slow.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried profiling your SQL to see why it's slow?  How much data are you retrieving with the select statement?

Comment: Where is it slow? Is the query taking a long time to run? Use sql server query profiler (if you are using sql server) to find out.

Comment: Also bear in mind that if you're rendering a lot of output as a table, the browser will wait until the entire table is downloaded before rendering.  If you use simpler markup, you might find that the page starts rendering earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got troubles with the line:

```
[Lote] like '{0}%'
```

when parameter is empty - SqlServer compare every simple record with '%'. In that case you could try hacking sql statement to:

```
'{0}' = '' or [Lote] like '{0}%'
```

which would make SQL server to evaluate only first part and skip the second one (like '{0}%') when {0} is empty.

---

But for future I'd suggest not touching sql statements from UI directly, that could make your application very rigid at some point. So you move everything to codebehind (and even better behind the codebehind, to Data Access Layer).